# Exportando datos a un csv con php

Tags: php, sql-server, csv, fopen, fputcsv

Estoy exportando datos de una vista en `SQL SERVER` a un archivo `.CSV` con  `PHP`, pero al descargar el archivo imprime código `html` , ademas no sigue el orden de las columnas ,por alguna razón la fecha me sale en la primera columna y el campo que debe ir en su lugar no aparece.

```
<?php 
 include "conexion.php";
    function genera_reporte(){
    $con = conectar_sql();
    $limitador = ";";
        // NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO Y CHARSET
        header('Content-Type:text/csv; charset=latin1');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Ventas_OXFORD.csv"');

        // SALIDA DEL ARCHIVO
        $archivo=fopen('php://output', 'w');
        // ENCABEZADOS
        $encabezados = array('SAL_ID', 'STORE_ID', 'SELLER_ID', 'SALE_DATE', 'PRODUCT_ID','QUANTITY','AMOUNT');
        //SEPARANDO POR (;) Y AGREGAMOS ENCABEZADOS
        fputcsv($archivo,$encabezados,$limitador);

        // QUERY PARA CREAR EL REPORTE
        $result=sqlsrv_query($con,"select top (10) * from FollowUp_CO_Ventas2");
        while($fila= sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
            fputcsv($archivo, array($fila[0],$fila[1],$fila[2],formato_fecha($fila[3]),$fila[4],$fila[5],$fila[6]),$limitador);
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['reporte'])){
        genera_reporte();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Lo primero que debes hacer es probar siempre tus datos. Por ejemplo, ¿qué ocurre dentro del `while`? ¿cómo saldrían las cosas si recoges un array general de los resultados y lo muestras fuera del `while`, algo así: `$allData=array(); while( $fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) { $allData[]=$fila; } var_dump($allData);`  Sería interesante que nos muestres el resultado de ese `var_dump`. De paso, con esa forma de leer puedes simplificar tu código, sin tener que meter las filas una a una. Eso sí, debes ajustar el `SELECT` para que traiga exactamente las columnas requeridas

Comment: este es el resultado: array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "317322"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "11"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "26C"
  [3]=>
  object(DateTime)#10 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2019-04-08 10:42:49.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
  }
  [4]=>
  string(8) "SN2513BA"
  [5]=>
  float(1)
  [6]=>
  float(3900)
}

Comment: Pues ya se ve algo muy raro ahí, en la posición `3` del array hay un objeto `DateTime` completo, incluso con la zona horaria y todo. ¿Te diste cuenta de eso? ¿Te interesa un objeto completo en tu CSV o solamente la fecha?

Comment: Me interesa solo D-M-A H:M:S

Comment: Dado que en la posición `3` del array hay un objeto `DateTime`, tendrás que hacer algo así: 
**`$allData=array(); while( $fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) { $fecha=$fila[3]->format('d-m-Y H:i:s'); $r=array($fila[0],$fila[1],$fila[2],$fecha,$fila[4],$fila[5],$fila[6]); fputcsv($archivo,$r,$limitador); $allData[]=$r;} var_dump($allData);`** Aquí `$allData` es sólo para depurar, luego lo puedes quitar. Observa que he querido crear la fecha en una variable aparte, para que se vea la diferencia. Prueba y dinos el resultado.

Comment: Muchas Gracias,ahora me entrega la información en el orden que corresponde, pero aun me imprime código html.

Comment: <form method="post">   
     <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-default" name="reporte"  id="reporte"><i class="file-excel"></i> Descargar reporte</button>    
                  </form>if (isset($_POST['reporte'])){
      genera_reporte();
    }

Comment: Encontré la solución para cuando imprime el código html,cree una llamo a mi función desde una pagina en blanco y listo

Comment: No se bien que hace `genera_reporte()`, puede que ahí se genere algún código HTML, tampoco sé si usas Ajax o algo así. Otra cosa, dado que usas `header` para el código final quita el var_dump y cualquier otra salida por pantalla. En este caso lo único que tiene que salir es el archivo CSV final.